# htaccess rule for 404 for all urls having "feed" word except when 2 urls

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone please help me in adding condition to htaccess rule for 404 page. Basically in htaccess I have set below mentioned rule for 404 for all urls having "feed" word except when below mentioned2 urls. This is wordpress site and feed word comes in the end of RSS feed urls. I have disabled feed now but could not remove these 2 urls from site header in home page.

The htaccess code I am using is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} feed [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

This code is working fine but I need to add exception in the rule for below mentioned urls i.e.

- http:// www. domain name.co.in/feed
- http:// www.domain name.co.in/comments/feed
  Both these urls shall open normally after setting 404 rule.

Comment: I tried this also but didnt work.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} feed [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "http://www.price4india.co.in/feed" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "http://www.price4india.co.in/comment/feed"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(comments/)?feed/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+feed - [L,R=404,NC]
```

Here:

- `!\s/+(comments/)?feed[\s?]` is a negative condition to fail the match if URI is `/comments/feed` or `/feed`. Trailing slash is optional.
- `.*feed`: will match `feed` anywhere in URI

Comment: Hi Anubhava, it worked all well except 2nd url i.e. http://www.price4india.co.in/comments/feed Still its showing 404. The negative lookahead is not working for this url. I have put this code live now though. Please improve for this url if possible. thanx in advance Jai

Comment: ok try my updated rule as your topmost rule

Comment: Thanx Anubhava for making my day. The code works perfectly as top most rule as well as anywhere in htaccess. Hope you have an amazing day. Stay Safe bro. thnx again Jai